# Websocket connection to failed on production host but it is fine in localhost django

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, asgi

I implemented websocket connection for live ubdation in by django application . The problem is it works in localhost but when i host the same application in public host server it not connecting .i used to host Daphne server

droping my code down below

myjavascript.js

```
  let urls=`ws://${window.location.host}/ws/socket-server/`

const Wsocket=new WebSocket(urls)

Wsocket.onmessage=function (e) {
    let data=JSON.parse(e.data)
    console.log(data)
    
    
}
```

consumer.py

```
# consumer.py
class SocketConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        self.room_group_name='test'
        
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type':'connection_established',
            'message':'you are noew connected'
        }))
```

```
#routnig.py
websocket_urlpatterns=[
    re_path(r'ws/socket-server',consumers.SocketConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

```
#asgi.py
application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        'websocket':AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                App.routing.websocket_urlpatterns          
            )
        )
        # Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)
    }
)
```

I used channels

```
settings.py
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
        }
    }
```

and i run my application command

daphne myproject.asgi:application

help me legends

Answer (score 3):

You are using an insecure websocket connection - "ws://". On your production server, you are presumably using a secure https connection. It is not possible to use an insecure websocket (ws) over a secure https connection. You will need to secure the websocket connection by using "wss://". See this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-secure-your-websocket-connections-d0be0996c556/) for how to do that.

This worked locally as localhost uses http, which is also insecure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use redis for production, use this cmd to install redis

```
sudo snap install redis
```

Then install the package

```
pip install channels-redis
```

run this cmd to check redis is working or not
(don't use redis-cli it will not work so use)

```
redis.cli
```

then,
replace the CHANNEL_LAYERS code to bellow

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default':{
         "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
         "CONFIG": {
                    "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
                },
    }
}
```

hope this will work,